# Can an outer system detect if a click is performed programmatically on a Button?

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have a button that calls another button2's `performClick()`. I want to know if there is any way to check or distinguish if the button2's click is performed programmatically or not.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
      button2.performClick()
}
```

Let's say I'm sending a request in button2's `onClick()` method. Can the system that I'm sending this request detect whether I performed this click via not actual click but this `performClick()` function.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to save a boolean value when the click is invoked via the performClick. Example

```
button2.setOnClickListener {
    //The click here is performed by clicking on the button itself
    buttonFunctionality();
}

button1.setOnClickListener {
    //Button 2 click performed via Button 1
    performedProgrammatically = true;
    buttonFunctionality();
}
```

Comment: I think I asked the question in the wrong way. I meant if there is any way that an outer system can detect the button click was made via this performClick() method.

Comment: I don't think that the system will be able to distinguish unless you tell it that it was performed via performClick by passing it some sort of flag